# Bokeh plot won't update

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm new to Bokeh and was wondering if anyone could help tell me why my plot is not updating? The code can be found here:

pastebin.com/rn36b3aY

The code it just supposed to grab some data using the function "get_dataset", plot a bar chart, and let me update the plot using a dropdown box and slider. Can anyone tell me why the plot is not updating? I can provide the data if it would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to run it? Bokeh server apps have to be run with the `bokeh` command, e.g. `bokeh serve --show app.py` If you are doing that already, what have you tried already to debug?

Comment: Hi, yes I've been using bokeh serve --show app.py. I've put a new, easier to read version here pastebin.com/rn36b3aY. The update is still not working correctly. It looks like this is due to the x=factors on like 57. Dataframe "asdata" has one categorical column (the first column) and one numerical column ( the second column). The numerical column seems to be updating, but not the categorical one. For example, if I switch line 57 to plot.vbar(x='y', width=0.5, bottom=0, top='y', source=source), the plot updates properly ('y' is the numerical column of the dataframe).

Answer (score 1):

can you post a simplified version of your program with data?

I suspect your plot might not be updating, because in your callback functions you use dataset_select.value and samples_slider.value to update the data. But these contain the values from before changing the Slider/Select. You should use the new argument.

See if this works:

```
def update_select_samples_or_dataset(attrname, old, new):
    global  X, Y
    dataset = new
    n_samples = int(samples_slider.value)

    asdata = get_dataset(dataset, n_samples)
    X = asdata[['aspects','importance']].as_matrix()
    source.data = dict(x=X[:,0], y=X[:,1])

def update_slider_samples_or_dataset(attrname, old, new):
    global  X, Y
    dataset = dataset_select.value
    n_samples = int(new)

    asdata = get_dataset(dataset, n_samples)
    X = asdata[['aspects','importance']].as_matrix()
    source.data = dict(x=X[:,0], y=X[:,1])

dataset_select.on_change('value', update_select_samples_or_dataset)
samples_slider.on_change('value', update_slider_samples_or_dataset)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding! After trying your solution, it looks like the plot still does not update correctly. Here's an updated, somewhat condensed version of the code:

http://pastebin.com/MLAigEG6

The two input data frames can be found here:

https://github.com/degravek/bdata

The slider is set to default at 15 (30 total values plotted). If the slider is moved, the axes for the plot don't update for some reason. For example, if the slider is set to 2, there should only be 2 bars shown, and the axes should adjust accordingly. Thanks a lot for taking a look.

Comment: You might have to update the axis manually with the command plot.x_range = ... in the callback functions.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it doesn't seem to work. Have you had a chance to look at the data at all? Still stumped.